# how to react redirect at the end of the function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I am using firebase email login authentication, once my login in successful i want to show home page for the user with the user welcoming message.
 At the end of login function i want to redirect to home page if login was succesfull, using react routers. the redirection should be automatic.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Auth.css';
import {Router,Route} from 'react-router';

// import{Router} from 'react-router';
// import {Link } from 'react-dom';

var firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/database');
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

class Auth extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      err: ''
    };
    this.login=this.login.bind(this);
    this.signup=this.signup.bind(this);
    this.teset=this.teset.bind(this);
  }

  login(event){
    const uname = this.refs.email.value;
    const pwd = this.refs.password.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(uname , pwd);

    promise.catch(e => {
      var err = e.message;
      console.log(err);
      this.setState({err : err});
    });
  }

  signup(event){
    const uname = this.refs.email.value;
    const pwd = this.refs.password.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    var promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(uname, pwd);
    console.log(uname,pwd);
    promise
    .then(user => {
      var msg = "Welcome "+ user.user.email;
        firebase.database().ref('users/'+user.user.uid).set({
        email : user.user.email
      });

      this.setState({ err: msg})
    });
    promise.catch(e => {
      var err = e.message;
      console.log(err);
      this.setState({err : err})

     });
  }

  teset(){
    this.props.history.push('/home');
    console.log("test valled");
  }

  render(){
    return(

<div id="form">
    <div className="logo">
        <h1 className="text-center head">The form</h1>
    </div>
  <div className="form-item">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ref="email" id="email" className="form-style" />
  </div>
  <div className="form-item">
     <input type="password" placeholder="password" ref="password" id="password" className="form-style" />
   <p><a href="" ><small>{this.state.err}</small></a></p>
      <a href="/Home.js">home</a>
  </div>
  <div className="form-item">
      <input type="button" onClick={this.login}className="login " value="Log In"/>
      <input type="button" className="login" onClick={this.signup} value="Sign Up"/>
      <input type="button" className="login "  onClick={this.teset} value="Log out"/>
      <div className="clear-fix"></div>
  </div>
</div>


    );
  }
}

export default Auth;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of react router are you using?

Comment: Please add the error you get!

Comment: "react": "^16.5.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",

Comment: i didnt get any error, but navigation is not done